# How can I achieve similar animation of the title "Flutter Animate Example" on an image?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation, flutter-animatedlist

I am using `flutter_animate 4.4.0`  package in my flutter app.

I am trying to achieve animation on a particular widget like the title of this Screen: [Animation gif](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gskinner/flutter_animate/assets/infoView.gif)

I am only trying to achieve the shade that runs in a loop on an image.

What I have done so far is:

```
Positioned(
        left: 93.w,
        top: 399.h,
        child: Image.asset(
          'assets/images/logo.png',
          height: 94.h,
          width: 224.w,
            ).animate(
                delay: 500.ms,
                onPlay: (controller) =>
                   controller.repeat(period: 500.milliseconds)).tint(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
                ),
          ),
```

I have also tried `Shimmer.fromColors()`. However, the `baseColor` property changes the color of the image.

I appreciate all of your kind help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use the `shimmer` package since `flutter_animate` provides that functionally as well, the additional color you are seeing is coming from the `tint` extension

Here is a working sample : https://zapp.run/edit/flutter-z43a06n743b0?entry=lib/main.dart&file=lib/main.dart

Code:

```
class ShimmerSample extends StatelessWidget {
  const ShimmerSample({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Image.network('https://i.imgur.com/nYxw0ES.png')
            .animate(delay: 500.ms, onPlay: (controller) => controller.repeat(period: 500.milliseconds))
            .shimmer(color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Looks like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/shimmer) to achieve that title animation.

```
    SizedBox(
  width: 200.0,
  height: 100.0,
  child: Shimmer.fromColors(
    baseColor: Colors.red,
    highlightColor: Colors.yellow,
    child: Text( // you can add any widget
      'Yor Text',
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      style: TextStyle(
        fontSize: 40.0,
        fontWeight:
        FontWeight.bold,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I am using an asset image and Shimmer.fromColors requires baseColor which changes the color of my image asset. @jaimin-raval

Comment: we can't do anything for that, use color according to your requirement